# Presto To Postgres Not able to query

Tags: postgresql, presto

I have made the connections from presto to postgresql. Describing of table is working but not select query.
Its giving the below error:

```
select rul_name from fms.fmref_schema.ru_tbl;

Query 20200521_122033_00164_rmrsd, FAILED, 1 node
Splits: 17 total, 0 done (0.00%)
0:00 [0 rows, 0B] [0 rows/s, 0B/s]

Query 20200521_122033_00164_rmrsd failed: com.facebook.presto.plugin.jdbc.JdbcSplit cannot be cast to com.facebook.presto.plugin.jdbc.JdbcSplit
```

Comment: I have never seen a problem like this. Can you please try with the latest [Presto 333](https://prestosql.io/download.html)?

Comment: Hi Piotr,We are already in production.I'm able to describe the table,but cant select any rows from the table